# Chrome is not launched for selenium through Jenkins

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am executing the chrome through selenium(TestNG programmed) with the help of Jenkins. Chrome is not launched.

Executing the same jar(All selenium tests) in the terminal is working fine.
Chrome is not launched when I executed the same jar using Jenkins.

Browser: chrome 58+,

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

**The error message is**

no such session (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'sureshautomation', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-53-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}] Session ID: 6e87715bb49201dffa32437749d3be9f

sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

Comment: Try to upgrade the browser version.

Comment: @SureshKumar Can you consider executing your `TestNG Suite` through CLI? AFIK, next it's a moments task. Thanks

Comment: @Guy I am already using the latest browser.

Comment: @Dev It is working fine in Terminal.

Comment: @SureshKumar Did you create a script & add it to Jenkins? Thanks

Comment: Yes, @Dev a bash script which in turn invokes TestNG suites programmatically. The script is working (Invoking the chrome) fine when I execute it in Terminal. But If build it on Jenkins then everything goes fine but the chrome is not getting opened. Thrown with the mentioned error.

Comment: You need to pass that bash script to Jenkins, for Jenkins to know how to execute the `TestNG Suite`. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145090/discussion-between-suresh-kumar-and-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added export DISPLAY=:0 and it works in my shell script before starting the selenium execution.